# Android application with phone book synchronization?

Tags: android, database, synchronization

I am creating one android test application , in which i have one button. On button click ,i want to synchronize phonebook records with my local database.If record in phone book is not in db table then insert it , otherwise leave it as it is. so how can i do this?

Comment: You need to create a custom sync-adapter. Refer this tutorial: http://ericmiles.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/connecting-the-dots-with-android-syncadapter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting contact list from your phone book you need write permission in `AndroidManifest.XML` (i.e. `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS`) .And you can collect contact list using following method.

```
          ShowContact()
         {
           ArrayList<String> nameList;
           ArrayList<String> phoneNoList;

           ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
           Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
           if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
          while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
               if(Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                   //Query phone here.  Covered next

                 Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                 new String[]{id}, null);
                  while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                // Do something with phones
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    nameList.add(name); // Here you can list of contact.
                    phoneNoList.add(phoneNo); // And here you can get list of phone number.You have to query separately for getting phone_no,email,name etc 
   // Here you have to iterate this(i.e. nameList) with your list in the database.And your rest of logic.

                } 
                pCur.close();                 
        }
     }      
   }
}
```

And Let me know if are having any issue in getting contact list.

Comment: how can i get cursor ("cur") according to display_name acceding?

Comment: You have to store contactName in ArrayList and iterate this list with your list of database to check weather contact exist or not.

Comment: @lakhani To get name of selected item in the listview you have to implement setOnItemClickListener() for listview.                 And use  String getSelectedItemOfList =(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)).toString(); to get selected item of listview.

Comment: @lakhani What exactly you want to do? You can declare your arrayList globally and use it anywhere.

Comment: @lakhani You can use dataset class i.e. getter and setter method to store and retrieve data.

Answer (score -1):

public static List fetchContacts(Context context) {
        final String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY;

```
    final String FILTER = DISPLAY_NAME + " NOT LIKE '%@%'";

    final String ORDER = String.format("%1$s COLLATE NOCASE", DISPLAY_NAME);
    final String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
    };
    ArrayList<MyContact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, FILTER, null, ORDER);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MyContact contact = new MyContact();
                // get the contact's information
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contact.setContactId(id);

                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                contact.setUserName(name);
                Integer hasPhone = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                // get the user's email address
                String email = null;
                Cursor ce = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA},
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                if (ce != null && ce.moveToFirst()) {
                    email = ce.getString(ce.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    ce.close();
                }
                contact.setEmailAddress(email);
                // get the user's phone number
                String phone = null;
                if (hasPhone > 0) {
                    Cursor cp = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI},
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    if (cp != null && cp.moveToFirst()) {
                        phone = cp.getString(cp.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        String timeStamp = cp.getString(cp.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP));
                        contact.setLastUpdateTimestamp(timeStamp);

                        String photoUri = cp.getString(cp.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                        contact.setPhotoUri(photoUri);

                        cp.close();
                    }
                }
                contact.setPhone_number(phone);
                contacts.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            // clean up cursor
            cursor.close();
            Utils.list = contacts;
            sendMessage(context);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contacts;
}
```