# How to get contact when user choose my app from Contacts's Complete Action Using menu

Tags: android

I am writing auto dialer. My main activity has an edittext to enter the telephone no or retrieve from contacts when they click "Add from Contacts". It is working fine.

Now, my requirement is that I need to add my app into Contact's Complete Action Using menu.

It is also done. But when user choose my app from complete action using menu, I want that selected phone no and set the phone no. on my main screen.

Now only my app is opened and phone no. is black.

I would like to know how to get that selected phone no. when they start my app from contacts.

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643229/android-application-with-phone-book-synchronization/11643681#11643681  hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer for my question.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action != null){

        // Set the user selected phone number when action lunch directly
        // from
        // contacts
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(INTENT_CALL_PRIVILEGED)) {
            setCallPrivilegedData();
        }
    }
    setCardSpinner();

}

private void setCallPrivilegedData() {
    phoneNumber = getIntent().getDataString();
    EditText phoneNoEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
    try {
        phoneNoEditText.setText(URLDecoder.decode(phoneNumber.substring(4),
                "utf-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have same problem here. Can you tell me how do you set the your dialer application onto complete action menu on android

Comment: Mark the question as answered even if you answer it yourself. I notice you do not accept answers when someone helps you. They will stop helping you if you do not accept answers.