# Select an Item from list view along with a button in android

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-listview

I have a button along with the List View in XML

The Button is for new contact and the list is for the List of Contacts. 
1.How to use ArrayAdapter/OnListItemClick on this List View ?

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Contacts.this, R.id.ListView));
```

Is This declaration correct ?

2.Is this method correct ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAddContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD CONTACT" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to display simple list

```
    String [] names = 
    { "a" , "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
            "a1" , "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1", "h1", "i1", "j1",
            "a2" , "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2", "i2", "j2",
            "a3" , "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3", "f3", "g3", "h3", "i3", "j3","j4"
    }; 

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names );
     yourList.SetListAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the way to use adapter.And for getting selected item of `listView` try this.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String  getSelectedItemOfList = yourList.get(pos); // here you can get selected item.
     }
   });
```

I think this is what you want. :)

Comment: Can names be an empty array ? Because what I am trying to do is a basic contacts application where in the List contains the names of people and the Button is New contact button.I dont want any initial display other than New Contact Button.

Comment: what exactly you want if you want contact in then read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643229/android-application-with-phone-book-synchronization/11643681#11643681.

Comment: Have you got it what you want?

Comment: First answer is more relavent