# set contact List from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, adapter

I'm having my own Adapter to list on `ListView` the picture and name of my contacts that I have on my `SQLite`. I have `ListActivity` that calls my `ArrayAdapter`, but it doesn't calls the `getView` and I don't Know why, and then the `setListAdapter` is empty I think.

I get the sample from : [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) and this is my code:

```
public class ListarContactos3 extends ListActivity {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ListAdapter dataSource;
private static final String fields[] = {"Nombre_Amigo","Picture","_id"};
Bitmap photo;
Cursor cur;
Context context;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
View view;
ViewGroup parent;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    DatabaseHandler helper = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    cur = helper.getAllContactList();
    Log.d("ListarContactos3","Cursor :"+cur);

    setListAdapter(new MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(this, cur));
    Log.d("ListarContactos3","setListAdapter");
}
 }
```

and this is my adapter:

```
public class MyPerformanceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 private final Activity context;
 private Cursor cursor;

static class ViewHolder {
 public TextView text;
 public ImageView image;
}

public MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(Activity context,Cursor cursor){
 super(context, R.layout.row_def);
 this.context = context;
 this.cursor = cursor;
 Log.d("MyPerformanceArrayAdapter","Constructor");
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  Log.d("MyPerformanceArrayAdapter","View");
 View rowView = convertView;
 if (rowView == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
   rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_def, null);
   ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
   viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Nombre_Amigo);
   viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView
      .findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
   rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
 }

 ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
 for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){

    byte[] bb2= cursor.getBlob(4);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb2, 0, bb2.length); 
    Log.d("MyPerformanceArrayAdapter","Bitmap: "+bitmap);

    holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    holder.text.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    rowView.setTag(holder);
}

return rowView;
}

}
```

and this is my method for the DataBase:

```
   public Cursor getAllContactList(){

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_AMIGOS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
            Contact contact = new Contact();

            byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PIC_SQ));
            Log.d("DatabaseHandler","blob: "+blob);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
            Log.d("DatabaseHandler","blob: "+bmp);
            contact.setPicSquare(bmp);
            contact.setID(cursor.getString(0));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
            Log.d("DatabaseHandler","setname: "+cursor.getString(2));
         }

        db.close();           
    return cursor;
}
```

can someone help me please? I don't Know how to show my contact list and it's important. thanks.

Comment: Read this post it will give information about how to get contact list in android http://stackoverflow.com/a/11643681/704374

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter's getView seems wrong. Looks like it's iterating over the whole cursor each time it is called.

Your adapter should extend SimpleCursorAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter, it is used when populating ListViews from a database. See [this post](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/) for an example.

That blog has a series on implementing CursorAdapters. You can find the list [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/category/android-tutorials/cursoradapter-tutorials/).

Comment: thanks for all, I just change my baseAdapter by SimpleCursorAdapter and modified some things and I list my contact list! thanks! now my problem is that I list always the same person, the first or the last.