# show List of all contacts with phonenumber in android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, contactscontract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read contacts on Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0)

Is it possible to create a `List` of my all `Contacts` with `PhoneNumber` in phone book , but condition is if it don't have `PhoneNumber` then it shows only name for that record. I want all this in my android application.I have stuck with this.

Comment: @lakhani A quick view of your profile reveals that you have already asked a similar question and have got/accepted the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643229/android-application-with-phone-book-synchronization

Comment: [This](http://vikasdp.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/custom-android-listview-to-read-phone-contacts/) will help you

Answer (score 0):

By this way you found all contact name that have no contact number.

```
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> **Read All contacts**

```
 public void readContacts() {
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
 Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
 null, null, null);

 if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
 while (cur.moveToNext()) {
 String id = cur.getString(cur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
 String name = cur
 .getString(cur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
 if (Integer
 .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
 System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

 // get the phone number
 Cursor pCur = cr.query(
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
 null,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
 + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
 String phone = pCur
 .getString(pCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
 System.out.println("phone" + phone);
 }
 pCur.close();

 // get email and type

 Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
 null,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
 + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
 while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
 // This would allow you get several email addresses
 // if the email addresses were stored in an array
 String email = emailCur
 .getString(emailCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
 String emailType = emailCur
 .getString(emailCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

 System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : "
 + emailType);
 }
 emailCur.close();

 // Get note.......
 String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
 + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
 + " = ?";
 String[] noteWhereParams = new String[] {
 id,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
 Cursor noteCur = cr.query(
 ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, noteWhere,
 noteWhereParams, null);
 if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
 String note = noteCur
 .getString(noteCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
 System.out.println("Note " + note);
 }
 noteCur.close();

 // Get Postal Address....

 String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
 + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
 + " = ?";
 String[] addrWhereParams = new String[] {
 id,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
 // Cursor addrCur =
 // cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
 // null, null, null, null);
 Cursor addrCur = cr.query(
 ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, addrWhere,
 addrWhereParams, null);

 while (addrCur.moveToNext()) {
 String poBox = addrCur
 .getString(addrCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
 String street = addrCur
 .getString(addrCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
 String city = addrCur
 .getString(addrCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
 String state = addrCur
 .getString(addrCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
 String postalCode = addrCur
 .getString(addrCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
 String country = addrCur
 .getString(addrCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
 String type = addrCur
 .getString(addrCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));

 // Do something with these....

 }
 addrCur.close();

 // Get Instant Messenger.........
 String imWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
 + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
 + " = ?";
 String[] imWhereParams = new String[] {
 id,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
 Cursor imCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
 null, imWhere, imWhereParams, null);
 if (imCur.moveToFirst()) {
 String imName = imCur
 .getString(imCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
 String imType;
 imType = imCur
 .getString(imCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
 }
 imCur.close();

 // Get Organizations.........

 String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
 + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
 + " = ?";
 String[] orgWhereParams = new String[] {
 id,
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
 Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
 null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
 if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
 String orgName = orgCur
 .getString(orgCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
 String title = orgCur
 .getString(orgCur
 .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
 }
 orgCur.close();
 }
 }
 }
 }
```