# How to filter Contact list with Firebase DB with phonenumbers

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a Firebase DB which is used as a backend for the Android App I'm developing. I app users have their mobile numbers considered as their Id which is stored in Firebase DB . While searching users in app ( phone contacts) it should show only the contacts which uses this app ( ie phone numbers which is already registered/available in Firebase DB ).

Tried searching and found something similar [[Android application with phone book synchronization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643229/android-application-with-phone-book-synchronization][1]) but not useful.

Appreciate help

Comment: Have you solved? It would be great if you could share your findings here.

Answer (score 0):

Store all your contacts in a HashMap using phone no. as a Key and name as a Value. Here I'm creating as

```
HashMap<String, String> phoneContacts = new HashMap<>();
```

and now call this method

```
void getFirebaseContacts(){

    databaseReference.child("ProfileData").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { //all users profile data

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map value = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = value.keySet().iterator();
                while (myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
                    String Mobile = (String) myVeryOwnIterator.next();
                    if (Mobile != null && phoneContacts.containsKey(Mobile)) {
                        //Mobile and it's associated details will be stored in local database and displayed to user..
                        Map userData = (Map) value.get(Mobile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```